# What is wrong with my JAVA do loop?

Tags: java, loops

I am learning JAVA and trying to write my first loop. The loop should prompt the user to guess a defined name.

The code is not performing right. I have tried to search for help on different JAVA tuturials both not found any examples where you guess a name/string but a lot where you should guess a number.

This is my code:

```
 /**
     *
     * @author mso_
     */
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class GuessName {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */

        public static final int C_Max_Trials = 10;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Define correct name
            String name = "Morten";
            String guessName;

            //Create a scanner
            Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Recieve a guess
            do {
            System.out.println("Please guess my name. Enter your guess here: ");
            String guessName = guess.next(); <-- ERROR

            //Create loop
            } while (guessName != name); <-- ERROR
                System.out.println("Sorry, wrong guess, please enter another guess: ");

              if (guessName = name); <-- ERROR
                System.out.println("Right on! ");


        }

    }
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried *reading* the error messages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### String comparison

You can't compare Strings like this. This will only compare the references. You must use the equals() method :

```
while (! guessName.equals(name));
```

A little explanation : http://www.zparacha.com/java-string-comparison/

### Variable redeclaration

There is another error in your code, you try to redeclare guessName inside the loop. You must declare guessName only once outside of the loop (ie before the `do {`).

### General mistakes

Thirdly, there's a some other errors in your code. I think all of them were pointed out in the others answer, but I'll do a quick list :

1. `if (guessName = name);` This is a useless statement as is, you must open a block : `if(condition) { statement; }`
2. Same line, your doing an assignment, not a comparison, and like said, with String you must use .equals()
3. The `System.out.println()` won't be executed when you think. Re-read the doc about do { } while() loop until you really understand them.

My advise : read carefully the error message of your compiler and read some doc before writing code.

Comment: `if (guessName = name);` is not only useless, it's not compilable as it's an assignment and `guessName` (as well as `name`) is a String, not a boolean.

Comment: yeah right, forgot that java won't even compile this. but an if statement like this is useless, assuming the condition is correct and don't change some values.

Answer (score 1):

What errors?

Use .equals when comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assignment operator and not the equivalence operator at

```
if (guessName = name)
```

you need to do

`if(guessName.equals(name))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing references (well, with `guessName = name`, you're actually assigning a value to guessName). Use `String.equals()` instead of `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing two objects. Not two string values. 
use `equals`

Answer (score 0):

That won't compile for a start - you declare `String guessName` on the third line of the main method, and then *declare* the same variable again within the `do` loop.  You should simply use the name of the variable to assign to it:

```
guessName = guess.next();
```

Because of this error, presumably your IDE's compiler doesn't see the variable at all, so the subsequent lines that refer to `guessName` are also flagged as errors.  Fixing this first line *should* clear those up, unless there's another problem lying there that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

The strings must be compared using the `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things there is a wrong semicolon after the if:

```
if (name.equals(guessName))  //removed the semicolon and use .equals 
   System.out.println("Right on! ");
```

and it's an assignment instead of a comparison as other answers state by now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class GuessName {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */

        public static final int C_Max_Trials = 10;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Define correct name
            String name = "Morten";
            String guessName = null;

            //Create a scanner
            Scanner guess = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Recieve a guess
            do {
            System.out.println("Please guess my name. Enter your guess here: ");
            guessName = guess.nextLine(); <-- ERROR

            if(!guessName.equals(name))
            {
               System.out.println("Sorry, wrong guess, please enter another guess: ");
            }

            //Create loop
            } while (!guessName.equals(name)); <-- ERROR


              if (guessName.equals(name)) <-- ERROR
                System.out.println("Right on! ");


        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the "<--- ERROR" when you copy past this answer, it won't compile otherwise ^^

Answer (score 0):

The line `String guessName = guess.next();` needs to be changed to:

```
guessName = guess.next();
```

Because "guessName" is already defined earlier.

Additionally, when you compare strings you need to use the method `equals` and not the operator `==`. So `} while (guessName != name);` should be:

```
} while (!guessName.equals(name));
```

And `if (guessName = name);` should be changed to:

```
if (guessName.equals(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the `javac` compiler says:

```
GuessName.java:26: guessName is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])
        String guessName = guess.next(); //<-- ERROR
               ^
GuessName.java:32: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: boolean
              if (guessName = name);// <-- ERROR
                    ^
2 errors
```

For the first one, you should not declare another local variable: drop the `String`. For the second, use `.equals` to compare `String` objects, as the doc says.

You will obtain something like that:

```
...
//Recieve a guess
do {
  System.out.println("Please guess my name. Enter your guess here: ");
  guessName = guess.next(); //<-- FIXED
  //Create loop
} while (!guessName.equals(name)) //<-- FIXED

if (guessName.equals(name))// <-- FIXED
  System.out.println("Right on! ");
}
...
```

which works correctly.